# What is a v1 in whatsapp business api's?

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

What is a v1 in whatsapp business api. for instance, `{{URL}}/v1/groups`. And the URL, should it be `"chat.whatsapp.com"`?

I am trying to play with Whatsapp business api like sending messages through api to different whatsapp id's. As a newbie, I want to know what really is v1 in the api. Unfortunately, whatsapp documentation doesn't have much information right now.

Comment: Giving your API a version number is just good practice for forward compatibility. There is no suggestion that there are other versions, planned or available, just an easy way to make the transition reasonably painless if and when the need arises.

Comment: Also, the URL should be the endpoint of your web container. If you're running on your localhost, the web container normally runs at 9090 port so your URL should be  ```https://localhost:9090/v1/...```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/dev-single-instance